# Where do I place .vim files? vim81 or vimfiles folders?

Tags: vim

I am trying to replace [dockerfile.vim](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vim/vim/master/runtime/syntax/dockerfile.vim) syntax, and when I do search on my machine I find these already installed:

```
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/ftdetect/dockerfile.vim
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/syntax/dockerfile.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim81/ftplugin/dockerfile.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/dockerfile.vim
```

Should I delete the .vim from both vimfiles, vim81 and replace with the new file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Vim sources `ftplugin` scripts and such it uses `:h :runtime` command which does search along `:h 'runtimepath'`. Normally all these scripts also have a guard against double inclusions (like `if exists("b:current_syntax")` etc.), so the first one gets an upper hand.

Hence, you only must ensure that you put your scripts in the first `runtimepath` directory, i.e. under `~/.vim/...` etc. There's no need to delete existing files from `/usr/share/vim/...`